# Stuck on Project Euler # 13

Tags: python

Please help me understand why my Python code to solve the [13th Project Euler problem](https://projecteuler.net/problem=13) is incorrect. I believe that I understand the task correctly and I think my code is correct, but it is obviously not.

```
number = '5000 digit number - see in the problem decription at the provided link'
list1 = [number[i:i+100] for i in range(0, len(number), 100)]
temp = []
for i in range(0, len(list1)):
    y = int(list1[i])
    temp.append(y)
print sum(temp)
```

Comment: You have not understood the task correct at all. It says - *one-hundred 50-digit numbers.* . Your code is assuming it to be *fifty 100-digit numbers* .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, the numbers are 50 digits long, not 100. Change this:

```
list1 = [number[i:i+100] for i in range(0,len(number),100)]
```

To this:

```
list1 = [number[i:i+50] for i in range(0,len(number),50)]
```

Second, you're printing the entire sum, rather than just the first ten digits. Try:

```
print str(sum(temp))[:10]
```

Answer (score 1):

Much simpler:

```
s = 'copied and pasted from the page'

result = sum(map(int, s.splitlines()))[:10]
```

Answer (score 1):

Only the 11 first digits need to be summed,

```
somme11=sum(int(number2[i:i+11]) for i in range(100))
print(somme11)
print( 'the ten first digits are' , somme11//1000)
```

Because the carry can't exceed 99.

```
4893024188690
the ten first digits are 4893024188
```

Answer (score 0):

An alternative is to load the numbers into a file and then just add them up, unless I too have completely misunderstood the question.

```
with open("sum.nums","r") as f:
    data = f.readlines()
total = 0
for i in data:
    total += int(i)
print "1st 10 digits ", str(total)[:10], "of total", total
```

1st 10 digits  5537376230 of total 5537376230390876637302048746832985971773659831892672

Answer (score 0):

It's pretty simple

```
def e13():
    f=open("100x50digits.txt")
    summ=0
    for line in f:
        summ+=int(line[:11])
    print(int(summ/1000))
    f.close()
e13()
```

Answer (score 0):

```
number = '''The 100 lines of 50 characters'''

numbers = number.splitlines()          #Devide the string into a list of strings.
numbers = [int(i) for i in numbers]    #Convert all elements into integers.
totalSum = str(sum(numbers))           #Add everything and convert to a string.
print(totalSum[:10])                   #Print the first 10 digits of the result.
```

The correct answer is 5537376230, checked with P.E.

The real challenge here is to deal with the really long string

Answer (score 0):

Use `StringIO` to take number as a input string and iterate trough elements by converting each one to a integer value

```py
from io import StringIO

number = StringIO(""" # Paste one-hundred 50 numbers """) 

print(str(sum(map(lambda x: int(x), number)))[:10])
>>> '5537376230'
```